# Eulerian approach to control volume and energy conservation equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, bernoulli-equation

After refreshing/researching the Eulerian approach to conservation equations for mass, energy, momentum I am struggling with understanding the partial derivative term that I believe represents accumulation of say energy ‘within’ the control volume - I think I can grasp its significance if the chosen CV us a contained gas or a if it’s a vessel volume (filling/emptying) but not if it’s a fixed volume of liquid - the presentation I see leads me to believe it can also apply to a fixed volume of incompressible liquid .. can it somehow or will the term always go to 0?

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific?  Please present the form of the equation you are referring to.  I'm thinking that, even if the mass of liquid in the control volume doesn't change, its internal energy can still change.  Your real question is, "how is the CV version of the energy balance applied in the limit of an incompressible liquid?"

Comment: Yes, given:    ɗN/ɗt (system) =  ∂N/∂t (CV) - ʃʃ nρvɗA (control surface) where N is energy

Comment: For emaple lower 1/2 of the liquid volume of a draining sink ..                   I have only found examples where the CV term is non-zero if the CV is a gas or if the CV is chosen as the inner volume of a tank that is draining -      Ultimately I am after a better understanding of the mathematical CV term above which is identified as “rate of accumulation within the CV”

Comment: What is "system" supposed to represent in this equation, and how does it differ from CV?

Comment: System= fluid volume or a system of particles       CV= A region in the flow field such as volume of tank, the entire volume of liquid or in the equation offered, a volume of liquid within the entire volume

Comment: Can you please provide a sketch to illustrate the difference between system and control volume is an example situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80194/discussion-between-arinla-and-chester-miller).

Comment: /Users/maryrapp/Desktop/IMG_4975.JPG